# python threading with sync queue

Tags: python, python-3.5

I have a script that follows the same logic in this sample.
Basically I insert items into a global queue and spawn threads with a while loop that gets and item from the queue and the calls task_done.

I can get the threads to join if my while loop is checking that the queue is not empty, but I wanted to try and incorporate a flag that I could set myself to exit the loop. When I try to do this, joining the thread blocks forever.

Here is the non-working sample that doesnt join the threads:

```
import threading
import queue

class Mythread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.signal = False
    def run(self):
       global queue
       while not self.signal:
           item = q.get()
           print(item)
           q.task_done()
    def stop(self):
       self.signal = True

q = queue.Queue
for i in range(5000):
   q.put(i)

threads = []
for i in range(2):
    t = Mythread()
    threads.append(t)

for t in threads:
    t.start()
q.join()

for t in threads:
    print(t.signal)   <---- False
    t.stop()             
    print(t.signal)   <---- True
    t.join()          <---- Blocks forever
```

Here is the one that works using queue empty

```
import threading
import queue

class Mythread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
    def run(self):
        global queue
        while not q.empty():
            item = q.get()
            print(item)
            q.task_done()

q = queue.Queue
for i in range(5000):
   q.put(i)

threads = []
for i in range(2):
    t = Mythread()
    threads.append(t)

for t in threads:
    t.start()

q.join()

for t in threads:
    t.join()          <---- Works fine
    print(t.is_alive())   <--- returns False
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Example tutorial:http://inventwithpython.com/blog/2013/04/22/multithreaded-python-tutorial-with-threadworms/

Comment: a thread pool is another possible solution. Your current code appears to be a crude reimplementation of the same logic.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

q.get blocks so it won't reach your while condition

Comment: since q.get blocks that means I should be able to safely use a while loop checking for whether the queue is empty or I can switch to True instead and just put None into the queue after q join to break out of the loop?